# How does NodeJS OS Module work

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, operating-system

Nodejs has a built in OS module that we can use by having this line in our code

```
var os = require('os');
```

There are a number of functions to use such as getting free memory, total memory, cpu usage, load average, etc.

My question here is **HOW** does nodejs calculate this information?

For example, the free/total RAM memory, how is that being done under curtains. Is it calling another process to read stats from the system? is it running a separate command like `iostat` or `dstat`? How is it actually retrieving that data for us?

Comment: You might be able to dig through [the source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/os.js) and find how it's implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `os.totalmem` function is a native function from `process.binding('os')` called `getTotalMem`. Their implementations can be found in the Node source code:

The following code can be found in [`src/node_os.cc`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/98e54b0bd4854bdb3e2949d1b6b20d6777fb7cde/src/node_os.cc):

```
static void GetTotalMemory(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  double amount = uv_get_total_memory();
  if (amount < 0)
    return;
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(amount);
}

// ...

env->SetMethod(target, "getTotalMem", GetTotalMemory);
```

The `uv_get_total_memory` function has [several implementations](https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=uv_get_total_memory&type=) based on the host OS.

Here is the Linux implementation [`deps/uv/src/unix/linux-core.c`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/63243bcb330408d511b3945c53719425d8b7abb8/deps/uv/src/unix/linux-core.c#L497-L503):

```
uint64_t uv_get_total_memory(void) {
  struct sysinfo info;

  if (sysinfo(&info) == 0)
    return (uint64_t) info.totalram * info.mem_unit;
  return 0;
}
```

The Linux build uses `sysinfo` to get this information. It does not need to spawn another another process.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I don't know why I got downvoted but this helps. Thanks